# Add Video Background Using PHP Inline Styles

Tags: php, jquery, css, video, html5-video

Is there a way to swap out the image URL and replace it with a video file for use as a background video instead of image?

Here's the code for my background image i want to convert to a background video :

```
echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body.front-page {
            background-image: url(' . esc_html( $image ) . ');
</style>';
```

I need to apply the video to this body.front-page class and not sure what the best method is however i would prefer using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should place a video like this:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then add some CSS to send it background:

```
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Working example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp